# How to reference template parameters of outer classes in innter classes?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code

```
template<typename T>
void f();


template<typename T>
class A{
    class B{
       void f(){
    
           f<T>();
       }   
    };
};
```

does not compile, and gives the following error

```
       <source>:10:15: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   10 |            f<T>();
```

What is the correct way to refer to T in the inner class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `f` is not the name of a template on that line.  It is the name of the method.

```
   ::f<T>(t);
```

Try that.